# Trabalhando com formulários idênticos na mesma página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá,
Preciso inserir o mesmo formulário duas vezes na mesma página.
Ambos chamam função javascript para preenchimento de campos automaticamente.
Exemplo, seleciona combo 1, ai preenche o combo 2, seleciona o combo 2 e preenche o combo 3 preenchimento via ajax.
Como cada campo pode ter apenas um id, e os formulários estão na mesma página, impossibilitando a utilização de id iguais, qual seria uma solução para poder ter esses dois formulários na mesma página, mas saber identificar qual formulário chamou a função javascript para poder preencher os combos corretamente.

Comment: Verifica, com javascript ou JQuery, se o 1° formulário foi setado (todos os campos) se sim, chame o ajax do formulário 2. Creio eu que cada formulário tem o seu ID.

Comment: @MarceloRafael entendi, mas como eu pego o id do formulário que está chamando a função js? a função javascript tem 3 paramentos já que passo

Comment: Cada formulário."html" está em um arquivo, e cada code.js está separado para cada arquivo? Ou você colocou todos os formulários juntos numa mesma página e colocou a tag <script> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja o código HTML abaixo.

```js
$(function () {
  $('input[type=button]').on('click', function() {
    formId = $(this).parent("form").attr("id");
    $('#flash').html('Botão do ' + formId + ' pressionado.');
  });  
});
```

```css
input[type='button'] {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1">
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
</form>

<form id="form2">
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
</form>

<div id="flash"></div>
```

> Pressione em "Executar" para ver este trecho de código em funcionamento.

Existem dois formulários iguais, cada qual com seu *id*. No JavaScript, com jQuery, atribui um evento de *click* nos botões, atingindo, assim, os dois formulários. Ou seja, o comportamento dos dois será exatamente o mesmo. Com a função `parent`, eu busco o elemento `form` em que o botão pressionado se encontra e, com isso, identifico qual dos formulários foi utilizado. Para verificar, basta ver a mensagem que aparece na *div* `#flash`.

> O trecho de código CSS foi apenas para deixar o visual um pouco mais limpo. Ele não é fundamental para o funcionamento da lógica.